# set custom code_challenge for loginRedirect in msalBrowser

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal, msal-react

I use msal-browser package for authentication and trying to set `code_challenge` to something which I want than the auto generated one by msal-browser.

```
import * as msal from "@azure/msal-browser";
import pkceChallenge from "pkce-challenge"

const msalConfig = {
  auth: {
      clientId: "GUID", // This is the ONLY mandatory field; everything else is optional.
      authority: "https://{tenant}.b2clogin.com/{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_signin_flow", // Choose sign-up/sign-in user-flow as your default.
      knownAuthorities: [{authority}], // You must identify your tenant's domain as a known authority.
      redirectUri: "http://localhost:6420", // You must register this URI on Azure Portal/App Registration. Defaults to "window.location.href".
  }
};

const b2cScopes = ["https://{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com/010eb29e-d42b-4ca3-9c16-1961a528ce67/tasks.read",
"https://{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com/010eb29e-d42b-4ca3-9c16-1961a528de77/tasks.write"];

const myMSALObj = new msal.PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);

const pkce = pkceChallenge();

const loginRequest = {
    scopes: ["openid", ...b2cScopes],
    codeChallenge: pkce.code_challenge
  }

myMSALObj.loginRedirect(loginRequest)
```

Looks like the above doesnt seem to work as the input param for `loginRedirect` doesnt expect `codeChallenge` property to be present.

How do I set this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible, these are the supported params
https://azuread.github.io/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/ref/modules/_azure_msal.html#authenticationparameters

Comment: The ask I've is, from websiteA (webA) login into websiteB (webB) using credentials of WebA through click of a button on WebA. To do this, I've setup a WebA's IdP in B2C, created a user flow to use WebA's IdP and set the redirect uri to WebB. In WebA a button will launch the user flow and on successfull auth will redirect to WebB, which gets a `code` in redirect URL. So far it works. But when I want WebB to call B2C to get `access_token` using this `code` I need the `code_verfier` created by WebA. How do I get this flow implemented ?

Comment: You should be linking to WebB from WebA, not trying to call the user flow directly. The link at WebA should be to the URL `https://webB.com/signIn`. Then WebB can initiate a proper request using MSAL itself, which automatically creates the code_challenge etc.