# Azure AD - Generate access token from code gives the error : The Code_Verifier does not match the code_challenge supplied in the authorization request

Tags: symfony, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I'm new to Azure and I need to implement a login flow using Azure AD for an application where the frontend retrieve the code and the backend have to generate the access token from the code already generated

On the FE side I'm using react with @azure/msal-browser and my source code looks like :

```
    publicClientApp = new PublicClientApplication({
      auth: {
        clientId: azureConfig.clientId,
        authority: azureConfig.authority,
        redirectUri: azureConfig.redirectUrl,
      },
      cache: {
        cacheLocation: 'sessionStorage',
        storeAuthStateInCookie: false,
      },
    });
    await publicClientApp.loginRedirect({
      scopes: azureConfig.scopes,
      prompt: 'select_account',
    });
```

Then I recieve a code : code=0.AU4AxXIC70Ma9ESVBt5raWVI_yqY9ha1CQhMgMGmdTdc8tODAAA...

On the BE side I recieve this code and I need to generate the access token and get user claims. To do this I have my symfony project with thenetworg/oauth2-azure package installed, so my code looks like :

```
    $this->provider = new Azure([
        'clientId'          => $this->parameterBag->get('azure_client_id'),
        'clientSecret'      => $this->parameterBag->get('azure_client_secret'),
        'redirectUri'       => $this->parameterBag->get('azure_redirect_uri'),
        'scopes'            => ['openid'],
        'defaultEndPointVersion' => Azure::ENDPOINT_VERSION_2_0,
    ]);
    
    $token = $this->provider->getAccessToken('authorization_code', [
        'scope' => $this->provider->scope,
        'code' => $code,
    ]);
```

But I receive this error :

```
invalid_grant AADSTS501481: The Code_Verifier does not match the code_challenge supplied in the authorization request.
Trace ID: 254744d9-ab7b-4c31-9dbe-0485bfd50501
Correlation ID: bb4a3ddf-6527-4b2c-98af-a124b66527d6
Timestamp: 2022-11-22 15:08:41Z
```

Any hint to get this done ?

Comment: Have you registered Azure AD app as `Single-page application (SPA)` while setting redirect URI in Portal?

Comment: Yes I did, with my localhost for test's sake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment via Postman and got below results:***

I registered one Azure AD application by selecting **Single-page application** in Redirect URIs like below:

[image]

It seems [@azure/msal-browser](https://azuread.github.io/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/ref/classes/_azure_msal_browser.publicclientapplication.html#acquiretokenbycode) library uses *Authorization Code Flow with **PKCE*** that needs **`code_challenge`**  to get **code** for **Single-page applications**.

I manually generated **`code_challenge`** using [**PKCE Generator Tool**](https://tonyxu-io.github.io/pkce-generator/) like below:

[image]

To get **`code`**, I ran below **authorization request** in browser:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantID}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=AppID
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope=openid
&state=12345
&code_challenge=Nj9Youq443xUOCe_HsmBXJy5dKC8YsqlUdn1sga3CR0
&code_challenge_method=S256
```

When I ran the above request by signing in with **admin** credentials, I got **consent screen** like below:

[image]

After accepting the above consent, I got **`code`** in address bar as below:

[image]

When I tried to generate **access token** with below parameters via Postman, I got ***same error*** as below:

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantID}/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:AppID
grant_type:authorization_code
client_secret:secret
scope:openid
code:code_from_above_request
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
```

**Response:**

[image]

To **resolve** the error, make sure to include **`code_verifier`** by removing `client_secret` if you are using **Single-page application**.

I got the **tokens** successfully when I included **`code_verifier`** like below:

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantID}/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:AppID
grant_type:authorization_code
scope:openid
code:code
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
code_verifier:S256
```

**Response**

[image]

In your case, try including **`code_verifier`** parameter in your code while generating token.

If the issue still persists, try updating your `msal-browser` version to **2.11.0**.

You can refer this **[GitHub](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/2691)** issue by ***thoo1*** for more details.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed response, I'm using msal-browser version 2.31.0, the problem is that I can't find how I can pass code_challenge and code_challenge_method while generating the code. also I found in this ticket that using the package I can't do that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69866121/set-custom-code-challenge-for-loginredirect-in-msalbrowser

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce step by step your solution but I get : AADSTS9002327: Tokens issued for the 'Single-Page Application' client-type may only be redeemed via cross-origin requests.

Comment: Are you getting error like [this](https://i.imgur.com/36U8f2I.png) in Postman?

Comment: Yes in Postman.

Comment: Try including **`Origin: *`** header like [this](https://i.imgur.com/OSaaU2z.png)

Comment: Ok, now I get the jwt token successfully. To get this done I need to find a way to include the code_challenge and code_challenge_method in azure/msal-browser

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249832/discussion-between-sridevi-and-khali).

Comment: sure, I'm writing in the discussion