# AADSTS900971: No reply address provided. on SPA with http://localhost as redirect_uri

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-active-directory, single-page-application

I am currently starting a Vue SPA application to join MS PowerBI and wanted to authentication with Microsoft.

In azure portal, we registered an application client as SPA and we gave http://localhost as redirect URI.

Then, on my view app, I run this code:

```js
const formUrl = `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${values.tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize`
  const params= {
    client_id: values.clientId,
    redirect_uri: "http://localhost:3000",
    response_type:"code",
    response_mode:"query",
    scope:"https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/.default",
    state:"mystate",
    prompt: "consent"
  }
  const url = new URL(formUrl)
  Object.keys(params).forEach(k => url.searchParams.set(k, params[k]))
  window.location=url.href ;
```

However, the login page always answers AADSTS900971: No reply address provided.

What can I do?

As asked in the comments, here is the configuration of my SPA

[image: SPA conf]

Comment: _"and we gave `http://localhost` as redirect URI."_ - that's not the same thing as `http://localhost:3000`

Comment: Could you include **redirect URIs** snip of your application from Portal by editing your question?

Comment: we tried to configure http://localhost and http://localhost:3000 in azure portal. Moreover the documentation explicitly says that Azure is not sensible to ports

Comment: Could you try adding redirect URI in `Web` platform by removing SPA and check if it works or not? Refer this similar issue that suggests the same https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1357913/aadsts900971-no-reply-address-provided-error-when

Comment: Thank You. This worked, I auto answered to ensure the solution is displayed for people having it in the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The error occurred as you are using **authorization code** flow by setting `redirect_uri` as SPA but it supports either authorization code flow with **PKCE** or implicit grant flow.

To **resolve** the error, you can switch to authorization code flow with **PKCE**  or remove SPA redirect URI and add it in **`Web`** platform in your app registration like this:

[image]

When I ran the Vue app now, it asked me to login where I got below **consent prompt** after signing in:

```js
const formUrl = `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${values.tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize`
  const params= {
    client_id: values.clientId,
    redirect_uri: "http://localhost:3000",
    response_type:"code",
    response_mode:"query",
    scope:"https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/.default",
    state:"mystate",
    prompt: "consent"
  }
  const url = new URL(formUrl)
  Object.keys(params).forEach(k => url.searchParams.set(k, params[k]))
  window.location=url.href ;
```

[image]

Once consent prompt is accepted, it redirected with **`code`** in address bar successfully like this:

[image]

If you prefer generating access token using authorization code flow with **PKCE**, you can check this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74538069/azure-ad-generate-access-token-from-code-gives-the-error-the-code-verifier-d/74545493#74545493) by me where I generated token via Postman.

**Reference:**
[AADSTS900971: No reply address provided. error when redirectURL is set and matches with request. - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1357913/aadsts900971-no-reply-address-provided-error-when) by **Shweta Mathur**

Answer (score 0):

Following the advices in comments, I applied the solution found on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1357913/aadsts900971-no-reply-address-provided-error-when.
The configuration of callback uri must be Web instead of SPA.

The reason behind this seems to be this:

> - The Single-page application platform specification (and its redirect URI type) supports both the auth code flow with PKCE and the implicit grant flow.
> - The Web platform selection, when used by a single-page app, supports only the implicit grant flow.